# Как узнать сумму разницы  максимальной цены и  минимальной и группированной по полю

Tags: sql, mysql

Как узнать сумму разницы  максимальной цены и  минимальной и группированной по полю

сделал так

```
SELECT SUM(MAX(`price`) - MIN(`price`)) as sum FROM test WHERE date >= CURDATE() GROUP BY shipping_id
```

но материться на группировку

Comment: А как материться?

Comment: Invalid use of group function

Comment: --
-- Структура таблицы `test`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `price`, `shipping_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 100, 1, '2013-12-08 20:57:05'),
(2, 200, 2, '2013-12-08 20:57:05'),
(3, 300, 1, '2013-12-08 21:02:43'),
(4, 20, 2, '2013-12-08 21:02:43');

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю что Вам надо сумму получить снаружи т.е. не для каждой группы а для всех.
Можно это сделать вложенным запросом, например так:

```
select sum(a.diff) as summ from (
SELECT MAX(`price`) - MIN(`price`) as diff FROM test WHERE date >= CURDATE() GROUP BY shipping_id ) as a
```

Comment: нет вернет null вот так возвращает 

все только по групам SELECT MAX(`price`) - MIN(`price`) as sum FROM test WHERE date >= CURDATE() GROUP BY shipping_id


а нужно сумму этого

Comment: Каким образом оно Null то может вернуть?

Comment: @ukroficer - оно может быть null только если все элементы выборки null